# Failing to remove stopped Docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to forcefully stop and remove all Docker images:

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`

However, I receive:

`Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 3b5b05d98767 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container deedefb82e27`.

As far as I understand, the container is restarting faster than the command tries to delete it.

Comment: What happens when you run `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` on its own? Do a `docker ps` to see if your containers are still active after that.

Comment: @RogerWang, yes, they are still active after docker stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in removing the image, not the container. This is either a race condition from the container not being completely deleted yet, or you have something else starting containers on the system like swarm mode.

For a race condition, just add a few seconds between the commands to give the rm time to finish on the server. Also there's no need for a stop since you're doing an `rm -f`:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) \
&& sleep 2 && docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

If you have containers running in swarm mode, first remove your stacks and services that you don't want to have running:

```
# something like this, will only work if you have stacks defined
docker stack rm $(docker stack ls --format '{{.Name}}')

# similar command for services
docker service rm $(docker service ls -q)
```

Each of those may take 10 seconds for the containers to exit, plus a few more seconds for the swarm manager to send the command, so you may want a `sleep 15` after they both return to give the server time to complete the request.

Comment: Thank you, the containers indeed were running in swarm mode.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to preface all of your commands with `sudo`, or ensure that you are already in a root shell.

For example:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q) && sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q) && sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -a -q)
```

Comment: Yes, your command has worked out successfully. But I still have running containers after it: `[oz@admin25 oz]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7511ecdec30e        dockersamples/visualizer:stable   "npm start"         18 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       8080/tcp            getstartedlab_visualizer.1.pl2og2hlv8htu9cjwdoc7ssvd
`